# Docker Postgres Not Listening to right port

Tags: postgresql, docker

I can seem to connect to postgresql running in docker. It seems that docker might be listening to the wrong port and I cant seem to get it to stop and listen to the port I want it to. Im using the docker python module to load a test my image/container and try and connect to the database. Everything seems to work in the surface until the install.py tries to connect to the docker database where I get:

> sycopg2.OperationalError: server closed the connection unexpectedly
> This probably means the server terminated abnormally
> before or while processing the request.

docker logs shows that the container started then stopped, then started again and seems to be listening to port 5432, which is the default for psql. I want 5433 since I have a non docker psql database running on the same system. I have been unsuccessful with getting docker to listen to the correct port.

```
waiting for server to shut down...2023-09-03 16:59:24.181 UTC [47] LOG:  received 
fast shutdown request
.2023-09-03 16:59:24.181 UTC [47] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
2023-09-03 16:59:24.182 UTC [47] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 53) exited with exit code 1
2023-09-03 16:59:24.183 UTC [48] LOG:  shutting down
2023-09-03 16:59:24.184 UTC [48] LOG:  checkpoint starting: shutdown immediate
2023-09-03 16:59:24.269 UTC [48] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 4473 buffers (27.3%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 2 recycled; write=0.023 s, sync=0.060 s, total=0.086 s; sync files=963, longest=0.001 s, average=0.001 s; distance=34921 kB, estimate=34921 kB
2023-09-03 16:59:24.285 UTC [47] LOG:  database system is shut down
 done
server stopped

PostgreSQL init process complete; ready for start up.

2023-09-03 16:59:24.415 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 15.4 (Debian 15.4-1.pgdg110+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit
2023-09-03 16:59:24.415 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
2023-09-03 16:59:24.415 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
2023-09-03 16:59:24.416 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2023-09-03 16:59:24.419 UTC [71] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2023-09-03 16:59:24 UTC
2023-09-03 16:59:24.423 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM postgres:12.15
FROM postgis/postgis
ENV POSTGRES_USER awdn
ENV POSTGRES_PASSWORD ****
ENV POSTGRES_DB awdn_data
ENV POSTGRES_PORT 5433
EXPOSE 5433
```

install.py

```
import docker,psycopg2

client = docker.from_env()
client.containers.prune()

try:
    container = client.containers.get('dbase')
    container.stop()
    container.remove()
except docker.errors.NotFound as e:
    print("The container is not running.\n")

try:    
    awdnunittest = client.images.get('awdn-unit-test')
    client.images.remove(awdnunittest.short_id)
except docker.errors.NotFound as e:
    print("No image exists for the unittest.\nThe psql image is being installed...\n")

client.images.build(path='./',tag='awdn-unit-test')

client.containers.run('awdn-unit-test',name='dbase',ports={'5433':5433},detach=True,publish_all_ports=True)

conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=awdn_data user=awdn port=5433 password=**** host=localhost")
```

Answer (score 0):

From your logs I can see the database process inside the container is still opening port 5432, so your changes are not active - for whatever reason.

But be aware you do not need to modify the container at all. Docker can forward the ports as you need it.

Since I do not use the python module I can only guess. Probably you need a line like

```
client.containers.run('awdn-unit-test',name='dbase',ports={'5432':5433},detach=True,publish_all_ports=True)
```

to send traffic you fire at port 5433 into the container on port 5432. Basically you'd need the equivalent of this command line:

```
docker run --name dbase --publish 5433:5432 --network=host -d awdn-unit-test
```

On the port directive, first mention the port outside, then inside the container. You want to connect on 5433, and Docker needs to forward the traffic to the container's 5432 port as that's where the DB is listening.
On top of that be aware that the container will be on it's own network, unless you use `--network=host`. To connect it to the host network follow this tutorial:
https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-host/

Comment: in [docker python](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/containers.html): `The keys of the dictionary are the ports to bind inside the container... The values of the dictionary are the corresponding ports to open on the host` so ports={'5432':5433} should be ok but still causes unexpected termination.

Comment: `docker run --name dbase --publish 5432:5433 -d awdn-unit-test` from the host (docker running on same computer) `psql -p 5433 -U awdn awdn_data` These calls give a connection refused

Comment: Your update does connect to postgresql for `psql -p 5432 -U awdn awdn_data` but I would like to use port 5433 on the host to connect to the docker psql

Comment: Your version does not work - and it is according to the documentation. Which IP does your psql client connect to? Be aware `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` won't work, so use your machine's IP.